# XSLT transversing

Tags: xslt

I am not sure how to go about this problem as I am pretty new to XSLT.

I am using an `xsl:for-each` to loop through the `Types`, which is fine but when I am in that loop(Type) how would I select the `Rate` using the attribute in the `TypeCode`? Am I right in thinking the select only has the scope of the for-each that I am in at that time? There could be many bag elements as well.

```
<Bags>
<Bag>
    <Types>
        <Type TypeCode="DBL">
            <Description Name="BLAH">
                <Text>BLAH</Text>
                <Image/>
            </Description>
        </Type>
        <Type TypeCode="JRS">
            <Description Name="BLAH">
                <Text>BLAH BLAH</Text>
                <Image/>
            </Description>
        </Type>
    </Types>
    <Plans>
        <Plan PlanCode="DISC" PlanName="Best rate">
            <Description Name="Best rate">
                <Text>Best available rate</Text>
            </Description>
        </Plan>
        <Plan PlanCode="NOCC" PlanName="No CC Required">
            <Description Name="No CC Required">
                <Text>Rate- No CC Required</Text>
            </Description>
        </Plan>
    </Plans>
    <Rates>
        <Rate TypeCode="DBL" PlanCode="DISC">
            <Rates>
                <Rate>
                    <Base AmountBeforeTax="0" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
                </Rate>
            </Rates>
        </Rate>
        <Rate TypeCode="JRS" PlanCode="DISC">
            <Rates>
                <Rate>
                    <Base AmountBeforeTax="0" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
                </Rate>
            </Rates>
        </Rate>
    </Rates>
</Bag>
    </Bags>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking the select only has the scope of the for-each
>   that I am in at that time?

**Not really**, an XPath expression can be *relative*, in which case it is evaluated off the current node, or *absolute* (starting with `/`) in which case it is evaluated off the current document node.

Even with a relative XPath expression it is possible to select nodes outside of the subtree rooted by the current node -- simply by using reverse axes or the `following::` or `following-sibling::`  axis.

**Use**:

```
ancestor::Bag/Rates/Rate[@TypeCode = current()/@TypeCode]
```

This assumes that bags cannot be nested, otherwise a slightly different expression needs to be used:

```
ancestor::Bag[1]/Rates/Rate[@TypeCode = current()/@TypeCode]
```

Comment: Cheers for that quick response, appreciated

Comment: @DazzlaJ: I am glad this answer was useful to you. Could you, please, *accept* it (by clickong on the check-mark next to the answer)?

Comment: I just have to say I have noticed over time that Dimitre really "gets" this XSLT stuff :) and provides nice answers on it.  Check his answers list!

Comment: Sorry Dimitre, just getting used to stackoverflow. Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to like to say thanks once again Dimitre, helped me out no end.